# 'enumerate' function breaks loop? python3

Tags: loops, enumerate

```
def main():
    x = open("textfile.txt", "r")
    #o = enumerate(x.readlines())

    for i in x:
        print(i, end="")



    x.close
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

If I uncomment the 'o' object this script will not run.
Could someone please tell me why that is?
:python3.3

Answer (score 0):

you mean you don't get output, right?

that's because x.readlines() isn't a generator - it actually reads all the data out of x. and then gives that to o, wrapped with an enumerator.

so when you do 
    for i in x:

there's no more data to be read - nothing to do.

you could do:
    for i,text in o:
         print '%d: %s'%(i, text)

and that would work...

Comment: But i dont change the for loop when i remove the comment, im still reading from object 'x', i dont call or involve 'o' but there is no output, how is it effecting my code? Sorry i'm a noob :)

Comment: so, readlines will read lines from the file until EOF. 'for i in x' also has the same behavior - the iterator across the file will read a line on every call until EOF. if you do the enumerate(x.readlines()), the readlines() part of it will read all the data and get to EOF. then you do 'for i in x', but x is already at EOF, so that actually doesn't go anywhere. you'll need to reset the file (either close/reopen, or do an x.seek(0) to return it to the beginning of the file, then it will work.